# Creating a singleton for my Core Data default stack in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, singleton

I am trying to use a singleton for Core Data.  Previously, I've been successfully able to do it by creating a class `CoreDataStack.h/.m`, calling the default stack method below, and its respective managed object context, in Objective-C, and works very well:

```
//RETURNS CoreDataStack
+ (instancetype)defaultStack {
    static CoreDataStack *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc]init];
    });
    
    return defaultStack;
}
```

However, I am using a Swift project, and I've been struggling to convert this into the latest Swift syntax.  How would I go about creating this?  This is my attempt so far:

```
class func defaultStack() -> Self {
    var defaultStack: CoreDataStack
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
       defaultStack = self.init()
    }
    return defaultStack
}
```

**and my Xcode generated error:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To create a singleton, use [Krakendev's](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) single-line singleton code:

```
class CoreDataStack {

    // Here you declare all your properties

    static let sharedInstance = User()

    private init() {
        // If you have something to do at the initialization stage
        // you can add it here. It will only be called once. Guaranteed.
    }

    // Add the rest of your methods here

}
```

You will call your methods and properties as `CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().property` and `CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().method()`. I recommend using something shorter instead of `sharedInstance`, like `service`.

This solution applies in general, not only in your Core Data case.